# Difference when comparing the timing results of performance API and chrome's developer tools

Tags: javascript, performance, fetch, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to time a `fetch` call. The following screenshot shows the time chrome developer tools show for a particular fetch request.

[image]

As could be seen for the request marked in red color, total time it took was `79 milliseconds`. Looks good.

When I try to time using the [performance api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance), the milliseconds are more than 100% at `163.46000001067296 ms`. How could that happen?

Here is what I am doing:

```
    loadInitVariables() {
        const queryString = this.formQueryString(this.queryStringParams);
        const t0 = performance.now(); // TIMESTAMP ONE @ T0
        return fetch(`${this.initVariablesPath}${queryString}`, {
            method: "get",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        })
            .then(response => {
                const t1 = performance.now(); // TIMESTAMP 2 @ T1
                log.debug(`Loaded init vars in ${t1 - t0} ms.`);
                return response.json();
            })
    }
```

Why this difference? If it could have been a few milliseconds i.e. +10 - +20, it would be okay, but it stands at more than 100%.

Am I not measuring this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this example, the time shown in the network tab consists of queing , starting ,stalled time(if any), sent ,waiting.

The time difference with `performance.now` seems excluding these numbers

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to just get the `TTFB` ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta Not sure if [PerformanceTiming.responseStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming/responseStart) can help

Comment: `var ttfb = navigationEntries.responseStart - navigationEntries.requestStart;`